# Jenkins Authorize Project plugin with internal SYSTEM user

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I added the `Authorize Project` plugin to my Jenkis server.

This is how I setup the access control for builds:

[image]

When the build is started by a user, then everything works fine, but when the build is polled and started automatically by the SYSTEM user, I receive the following warning:

[image]

What can be wrong with my setup?

Comment: We experience the same issue. Were you able to solve the problem or did you end up ignoring this message?

Comment: Not yet. In case you find a solution earlier then please post it here.

Comment: Maybe you can report it on the official issue tracker? https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-60508?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20component%20%3D%20authorize-project-plugin

Comment: Sure, I will do it. Thanks!